# have error in getVideoDevices connectycube in react-native-webrtc

Tags: react-native, webrtc, connectycube

i wrote this code :

```
getVideoDevices() { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
           ConnectyCube.videochat.getMediaDevices('videoinput').then(devices => { 
           devices ? resolve(devices) : reject(); 
          }); 
    });
 }
```

but i have this error in console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.enumerateDevices')
```

all of permission such as camera and microphone set